# Where machine instructions of a program stored during runtime?

Tags: c++, memory-management

So far as I know, whenever we run any program, the machine instructions of the program is loaded in RAM. Again, there are two regions of memory: stack and heap.

My question is: Which region of memory the machine instruction stored in? stack or heap?

I learnt that the following program gives a runtime error though there is no variable declared inside the function. The reason behind this is the overflow of stack. Then should I assume that the machines instructions of the function is stored in stack?

```
int func()
    {
            return func();
    }
```

Comment: It depends upon the operating system, but the text segment is usually neither stack nor heap

Comment: how and why it is tagged `c++11` specifically?

Comment: Please do not edit the question and add one more ___completely different___ question into it. Ask a new one.

Comment: @das, I am currently using c++. That's why I wanted to know how memory is managed for c++ programmes.

Comment: Your new question has absolutely nothing to do with the first one. The reason it crashes is because function calling parameters such as the return address are stored on the stack. The machine code itself is not.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, actually i'm new here. I'll try not to do this in future.

Comment: @MuktadirRahman No problem. and keep an eye for formatting also. Cheers !!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you care where machine instructions are stored?

Comment: Actually I was solving recursion related problem. Then I noticed that the code described in the question gives runtime error. But i could not find any reason behind this. That's why i wanted to know. @JohnDibling

Comment: @MuktadirRahman: Well, that runtime error / stack overflow **is** the problem you get when you're looking at a recursion that does not terminate. ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither, as it is not *dynamically* allocated the way stack and heap are.

The executable loader loads the executable (.text) and any static data it contains, like the initial values of global variables (.data / .rodata), into an unused RAM area. It then sets up any zero-initialized memory the executable asked for (.bss).

Only *then* is the stack set up for `main()`. Stack memory is allocated on the stack if you enter another function, holding the return address, function arguments, and any locally declared variables as well as any memory allocated via `alloca()`.[1] Memory is released when you return from the function.

Heap memory is allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`. It gets released when you `free()` or `realloc()` it.

The RAM used for the executable and its static data does not get released until the process terminates.

Thus, stack and heap are, basically, under control of the application. The memory of the executable itself is under control of the executable loader / the operating system. In appropriately equipped operating systems, you don't even have write access to that memory.

---

Regarding your edited question, no. (Bad style, editing a question to give it a completely new angle.)

The executable code remains where it was loaded. *Calling* a function does *not* place machine instructions on the stack. The only thing your `func()` (a function taking no arguments) places on the stack is the *return address*, a pointer that indicates where execution should continue once the current function returns.

Since none of the calls ever returns, your program keeps adding return addresses on the stack, until that cannot hold any more. This has nothing to do with machine code instructions at all.

---

[1]: Note that none of this is actually part and parcel of the C language standard, but *implementation-defined*, and may differ -- I presented a simplified version of affairs. For example, function parameters might be passed in CPU registers instead of on the stack.

Comment: If not, then where machine instructions are stored ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't the heap be statically allocated too (global variables, for example)?

Comment: @Yellows: Writing an elaboration right now. You are wrong, btw. ;)

Comment: A little more help please. The following code also gives runtime error. Why? There's no return address.

void func()
{
        func();
}

Comment: @MuktadirRahman: The return *value* of the function does not matter, there is still a return *address* added to the stack. The two are different things. -- I just realized I had a major brain fart when writing what the return address **is**. It's of course not a pointer into the *stack*, it's a pointer into the *executable code*. Edited the answer accordingly. (Less coffee, more thinking. :-D )

Comment: Many people say stack is statically allocated(the stack size is calculated at compile time). Who's right? I think the stack "grows up" and stack overflow can happen, so it seems like the stack is kinda dynamic. Could somebody please clear this out?

Comment: @starriet: As I said, it is implementation-defined, as the standard does not mention "stack" at all. Where stack is used (which, admittedly, is almost everywhere), it is *not* set at compile time, because the compiler has no way of knowing how deep your call stack might get. Some systems can grow stack dynamically, others assign it statically at startup... it's a complex topic far beyond a SO comment.

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you for your reply :) Then what happens in the "usual" case? such as Windows/macOS/Linux, and a typical c++ environment. Also, as you said, if the compiler has no way of knowing how the size of the call stack will be, then how can some systems assign it statically? (yeah you're right, it's a complex topic, but I couldn't help myself asking you again!)

Comment: @starriet Systems with memory virtualization (like Windows and Linux) *used* to load the executable at the lowest memory, and assigned initial stack at the highest memory (just below the OS itself). Heap allocations would grow from after the executable upwards, while stack would grow downwards until you run out of memory. Systems without virtualization (like classic AmigaOS) would usually assign a stack of size X, which is usually configurable. And if you ran out of that, well, you ran out of memory. {shrug} In no case though (that I know of) was stack size determined at compile time.

Comment: (ctd.) That would be the case if you're looking at really restricted embedded environments, where there is no operating system and no loader that could assign a configurable stack size. -- Today, modern systems "randomize" their memory space, so things no longer reside at predictable (virtual) addresses. This makes it harder for malware, but also for those trying to explain memory layouts. :-D And in any case, you should never, ever have to actually think about this, because when you start to exploit these kind of details, you've left the realm of well-behaved conforming programming...

Comment: @DevSolar Please correct me if I got wrong. In typical situations, if we run a program, the *OS* allocates some fixed-sized memory to that program, whether or not it uses memory virtualization. Then, *the program itself* uses some part of the allocated memory as a stack or heap, dynamically during the runtime. When you mentioned "stack and heap are dynamically allocated", that means stack and heap are dynamically used by the *program* (but the whole memory was allocated *statically* by the *OS*). Am I right? Thank you so much, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @starriet Not really. The process does *not* get the whole range of virtual memory. That would be inefficient as mapping all those pages in turn eats (physical) memory. The process gets enough memory for the executable and its static data at low addresses (ignoring memory space randomization for now), and a "starting stack" at high addresses. The range in between is not mapped. If the user-space memory management (malloc) needs more heap memory, it makes a system call to the OS which in turn extends the heap upwards. If the stack runs full, the OS detects that and extends the stack downward.

Comment: (ctd.) If the whole range of virtual memory were mapped, the OS could no longer detect illegal memory accesses (SEGFAULT), for one thing.

Comment: @DevSolar So the entire memory for the process is not allocated at the beginning, but as the stack and heap grow up towards each other, OS allocates more memory. When they meat each other, then stack overflow(or heap overflow?) occurs.  So, the OS allocates the memory for stack and heap dynamically, but the maximum memory size is fixed, because the address of the "starting stack" is fixed and *not changed* even if the process needs more memory? (I'll try to cut down my endless questions! :)

Comment: @starriet: The address of the stack could not be changed to make more room anyway, because it *already is at the highest available address*. You are talking complete exhaustion of the virtual memory space here. Your system would likely been swapping itself to death long before that, because it is unlikely you have even a fraction of that amount of **physical** RAM to back it all up...

Answer (score 4):

Neither one nor the other.

The image of your program contains the code and the static data (f.e. all you string constants, static arrays and structures, and so on). They will be loaded into different segments of the RAM.

Stack and heap are dynamic structures to store data, they will be created at the start of your program. Stack is hardware supported solutions, while heap is a standard library supported solution.

So, your code will be located in the code segment, your static data and heap will be located in the data segment, and the stack will be located in the stack segment.

Answer (score 3):

> the machine instructions of the program is loaded in RAM

Correct for hosted, "PC-like" systems. On embedded systems, code is most often executed directly from flash memory

> Again, there is two regions of memory: stack and heap.

No, that's some over-simplification that way too many, way too bad programming teachers teach.

There are lots of other regions too: `.data` and `.bss` where all variables with static storage go, `.rodata` where constants go, etc etc.

The segment where the program code is stored is usually called `.text`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither heap nor stack.

Usually, executable instructions are present in [Code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment).

Quoting the wikipedia article

> In computing, a code segment, also known as a text segment or simply as text, is a portion of an object file or the corresponding section of the program's virtual address space that contains executable instructions.

and

> when the loader places a program into memory so that it may be executed, various memory regions are allocated (in particular, as pages)

At runtime, the code segment of an object file is loaded into a corresponding code segment in memory. In particular, it has nothing to do with stack or heap.

---

EDIT:

In your code snippet above, what you're experiencing is called *infinite recursion*.

Even if you function does not need any space in stack for local variable, it **still needs to *push* the return address** of the *outer* function before calling the *inner* function, thus claiming the stack space, only never to `return` [*pop* the addresses out of stack] [like *at a point of no return*], thereby running out of stack space, causing stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> Again, there is two regions of memory: stack and heap.

It's not that simple. Normally on mainstream operating system there's more stuff going on:

- there is one stack per running thread;
- there are as many heaps as you decide to allocate (actually, as far as the memory manager is concerned you ask some memory pages to "enabled" in your virtual address space, the "heap" thing derives from the fact that normally one uses some kind of heap manager code to efficiently distribute these memory portions between allocations);
- there can be memory mapped files and shared memory;
- most importantly, the executable file (and the dynamic libraries) are mapped in the memory of the process, normally with the code zone (the so called "text" segment) mapped in read-only mode, and other zones (typically pertaining to initialized global and static variables and stuff fixed by the loader) in copy-on-write.

So, the code is stored in the relevant section of the executable, which is mapped in memory.

Answer (score 1):

They are usually on a section called `.text`.

On Linux you can list the sections of an ELF object or executable with `size` command from core-utils, for example on a `tst` ELF executable:

```
$ size -Ax tst | grep "^\.text"
.text                0x1e8   0x4003b0
$
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple memory segments in addition to the stack and heap.  Here's an example of how a program may be laid out in memory:

```
              +------------------------+
high address  | Command line arguments |   
              | and environment vars   |  
              +------------------------+
              |         stack          |
              | - - - - - - - - - - -  |
              |           |            |
              |           V            |
              |                        |
              |           ^            |
              |           |            |
              | - - - - - - - - - - -  |
              |          heap          |
              +------------------------+
              |    global and read-    |
              |       only data        |
              +------------------------+
              |     program text       |
 low address  |    (machine code)      |
              +------------------------+
```

Details will vary from platform to platform, but this layout is pretty common for x86-based systems.  The machine code occupies its own memory segment (labeled `.text` in ELF format), global read-only data will be stored in another segment (`.rdata` or `.rodata`), uninitialized globals in yet another segment (`.bss`), etc.  Some segments are read-only, some are writable.